# Angular 4: initializing data in a service to be used by all components

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and building an app to display course info for different subjects. I have to make a rest call to get all the subjects. I then want to share this data with all the controllers.

I have created a service that has getSubjects() method. How can I call this method to initialize the subjects data so that it is available to be used by all the controllers? I tried to call this in app.component.ts ngOnInit()

But when I try to use it in my components the subject is initially undefined and it changes later. How can I handle this undefined object and update the component once subject data is available?

In short where should I initialize my data in a service method so that it is available to be used by all the components?

I tried to implement the solution using APP_INITIALIZER however it doesn't block my app and end up giving empty subjects data.

my service has load function:

```
subjects: Subject[] = [];
load() {

        return this.getSubjects().subscribe(
          subjects => this.setSubjects(subjects),
          err => { console.log("something went wrong");
        }
    );
}
getSubjects(): Observable<Subject[]> {
        return this.http.get<Subject[]>(this.Url)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getSubjects', []))
        );
}

setSubjects(s: Subjects[]): void {
        this.subjects = s;

}
```

module.ts file has:

```
export function trainingProviderFactory(service: TrainingService) {
  return () => service.load();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346515/angular-access-data-from-service

This question is answered in the post, you want to use an APP_INITIALIZER service

Answer (score 2):

The components should not care if the data is reused or not. Request the data from the service in `OnInit` like you would any other request you want to load when the component is loaded.

In the service persist the observable and return the same observable once it has been assigned a value. Any components that consume the method of the service will access the same materialized value once it has been retrieved.

```
private myReusedObservable: Observable<any>;
getData(): Observable<any> {
    if (!this.myReusedObservable)
        this.myReusedObservable = this.http.get<any>('urlHere');
    return this.myReusedObservable;
}
```

*Note: Replace `any` with the model definition you want to use.*